# difference between two hours - to find hours slept

Tags: r, datetime

I need to be able to find hours slept. I would also like the output to be in hours and minutes
if you only have wakeup time and bedtime and no date. Also some bedtimes are after 12am. in R
I tried this

```
sleepTime <- function(bed, wake){
  wake <- paste(Sys.Date(), wake)
  tmpbed <- paste(Sys.Date(), bed)
  d <- apply(data.frame(tmpbed, wake), 1, function(x) difftime(x[2], x[1], units = "hours"))
  adjust <- -(d < 0) 
  tmpbed <- paste(Sys.Date() + adjust, bed) 
  apply(data.frame(tmpbed, wake), 1, function(x) difftime(x[2], x[1], units = "hours"))
}
```

which works, but only gives out hours. Also I dont understand how this code works so if it could be explained or made more basic that would be great :)

Comment: Can you post sample input?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with package `chron`. It's vectorized and returns times in `hh:mm:ss` format.

```r
library(chron)

sleepTime <- function(bed, wake){
  wake <- paste(Sys.Date(), wake)
  tmpbed <- paste(Sys.Date(), bed)
  d <- apply(data.frame(tmpbed, wake), 1, function(x) difftime(x[2], x[1], units = "hours"))
  adjust <- -(d < 0) 
  tmpbed <- paste(Sys.Date() + adjust, bed) 
  apply(data.frame(tmpbed, wake), 1, function(x) difftime(x[2], x[1], units = "hours"))
}

sleepTime2 <- function(bed, wake) {
  if (!require("chron")) {
    # install.packages("chron")
    # require("chron")
    stop("there is no package called 'chron'")
  }
  b <- ifelse(nchar(bed) < 6, paste0(bed, ":00"), bed)
  w <- ifelse(nchar(wake) < 6, paste0(wake, ":00"), wake)
  b <- chron("1/1/2000", b)  # chron() needs a date, this one
  w <- chron("1/1/2000", w)  # or any other date
  adjust <- -(w - b < 0)
  b <- b + adjust
  w - b
}

w <- c("8:00:00", "7:00:00")
b <- c("23:00:00", "12:30:00")

sleepTime(b, w)
#> [1]  9.0 18.5

sleepTime2(b, w)
#> [1] 09:00:00 18:30:00
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

The return value of `sleepTime2` is a vector of class `"times"`. Hours, minutes and seconds can be extracted with appropriate extractor functions.

```r
d <- sleepTime2(b, w)

class(d)
#> [1] "times"

hours(d)
#> [1]  9 18
minutes(d)
#> [1]  0 30
seconds(d)
#> [1] 0 0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>